# How to allow shelving but not checking-in?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, changeset, shelve, shelveset

Is it possible to grant a second developer the right to create shelve sets without allowing him to check-in or commit the changes directly to the code base?

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: [Shelve and Unshelve Pending changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): "No permissions are required to perform the shelve task" (Of course, they'll have needed `Read` permission to create the set of changes in the first place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deny that user or group the Check-in permission, see [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#VersionControl), but it is better to remove the permission.